# $ is not defined jQuery 3.5.1 window on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have jQuery as a script source before my custom `site.js` file.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/site.js"></script>
```

In `site.js` I have the following:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    console.log('test');
});
```

The following is the output from the console:

```
VM318 site.js:142 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at VM318 site.js:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM318 site.js:1
site.js:2 test
```

I am not sure what I am missing here? I have written a function to test jQuery and it works in `site.js`:

```
function testFunc() {
    let test = $('#test');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the script elements in that order? Any other script that is loaded in-between?

Comment: What about trying `jQuery(window).on('load')`? jQuery should put `$` in the global namespace, but perhaps that is being overwritten later?

Comment: @trincot - I do have bootstrap before site.js, but that is it. That is the order: jQuery, bootstrap, site.js

Comment: Do you get the error when you remove bootstrap temporarily?

Comment: @trincot Yes, same error

Comment: I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: Check your browser tools (F12) network/console for errors - maybe you have the wrong path to jquery

Comment: @romellem - Yes, it does. Somehow jquery is not being loaded in first. I will need to do some further review, thank you.